# Android открыть приложение по ссылке

Tags: android, android-intent, intent-filter, deeplink

Есть MainActivity, которое хочу открывать по ссылке. Для этого расписал в манифесте:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="mysite.net"/>
            </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

Обработка в MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(getIntent().getData() != null) {
        showSomething(getIntent().getData().toString());
    }
}
```

Вопрос: почему в случае, если приложение находится в бэкграунде я получаю Intent с нулевой датой, а если приложение закрыто, то прекрасно получаю нужные данные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам должно помочь переопределение метода `void onNewIntent(Intent intent)` в который должен приходить обновлённый интент. Если его в этом методе назначить интентом активити (`setIntent(intent)`), то в дальнейшем и `getIntent()` должен будет возвращать нужный экземпляр оного.

Comment: все верно, вы как всегда правы)спасибо